# Chaotic solutions to mixed integer linear problems

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Is there a way to get the branch and bound algorithm to converge to a solution "close" to an initial value?

One way I can think of, is to adding a "distance from initial value" term to the cost function. However, this makes the linear problem quadratic.

To give you a brief understanding of the problem I am working on:

> Machines are to be allocated to various factories in certain packaging formats. Thus when 
>   the required capacity increases, my code throws up solutions where too many machines get relocated.

How do I get to the optimum solution which is closest to the current machine configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the linearity. Just minimize the sum of the absolute values the differences. Instead of

```
min abs(x)
```

use

```
min (zp + zm)
s.t.  
    x = zp - zm
    zp >= 0
    zm >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Also found a useful bag of tricks [on the AIMMS website](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_linearprogrammingtricks.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that is a good document. This trick with the absolute values is 6.1 in it. Anyway, good luck!